# How can I make CommandBar render in Xamarin Forms UWP?

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, mvvmcross

I have a ContentPage (actually an MvxContentPage) with ToolbarItems defined. The Items appear in Android and iOS as expected, but do not appear at all in UWP. I have tried setting SetToolbarPlacement to both Top and Bottom manually, in both the constructor and the OnAppearing method. Thus far, I have not been able to affect any change in the UWP application. Am I doing something wrong? Can Mvx not render the Toolbar?

```
<mvx:MvxContentPage
    xmlns:mvx="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
    x:TypeArguments="viewModels:CategoryListViewModel"
    xmlns:viewModels=""
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="GSP.X.AccuStore.Forms.Views.Site.Profiles.CategoryListView">

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Areas" Command="{Binding Path=GoToAreasCommand}" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

</mvx:MvxContentPage>
```

Comment: What version of Xamarin Forms are you using?

Comment: Xamarin.Forms v3.2.0.871581

Comment: You mentioned MvvmCross below. What version of Mvx are you using?

Comment: We are using 6.1.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have not add start page to  `NavigationPage`. I have test with the follow code in the blank **Xamrin.Froms** app, the `ToolbarItem` display well in the top of MainPage.

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var nav = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
    MainPage = nav;
}
```

Comment: With MVX, the NavigationPage is created outside of my scope. But, my initial View is definitely created within the context of a NavigationPage or iOS and Android would not have their navigation bars and the application would not navigate between the couple dozen pages on any of the platforms, right?

Comment: I have created xamrin app with [MvvmCross SolutionTemplate](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PaulDatsiuk.XamarinFormswithMvvmCross5SolutionTemplate) and ToolbarItem  display in my side.

Comment: Thank you for the solution template. Here's what it did for us:
1. Got us to upgrade both MvvmCross and Xamarin Forms to the most modern versions. By doing that, we got the CommandBar to display.
2. Showed us how to follow the upgrade path from 6.1.2 to 6.2.2 (something they don't document themselves).

Comment: Looks like it works with mvx 6.2.2, but not with mvx 6.1.2.